# Making the console disappear and reappear shows momentarily on startup

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, console, show-hide

I have a GUI application where the [console is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206306/hiding-the-console-window-after-reading-input) (using the `pyw` extension does not seem to allow the console to reappear) but now I need to make it reappear to allow user input.  Here is my code currently:

```
import ctypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')

SW_HIDE = 0

hWnd = kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()
user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE)


import tkinter as tk

def show_console():

    kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')
    user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')

    SW_SHOW = 5

    hWnd = kernel32.GetConsoleWindow()
    user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW)

tk.Frame()

a = tk.Button(text = 'Make Console Appear', command=show_console)
a.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

This hides and shows the console as desired however when it is first launched the windows shows briefly, then disappears.  How can I prevent this?

Comment: I think it's probably not possible. AFAIK the console appears when the python process starts, and it's visible until your program is loaded, parsed, and executed. Besides, I think what you're trying to do is ill-advised. If the user's PC is configured to show a python terminal while a python program is running, why would you go out of your way to hide that window? What if the user *wants* to see it? What if I'm working in a terminal and I start your program, and it hides the terminal that I was trying to work with? Why do you want to hide and show the terminal like this?

Comment: @Aran-Fey  I see what you are saying in the first part.  
So what should I do?  Create a second script and launch that as a separate visible console, rather than trying to integrate everything into one?

Comment: To answer your question I am building a desktop application with its own custom terminal.  When a button is clicked I need the terminal to open.

Comment: I think you should stop trying to hide the terminal. If you want your own custom terminal, why not implement one with a tkinter dialog and a textarea?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I see.  Then make it a child window.  OK I think that might work.  Thanks

Comment: A GUI application doesn't automatically attach to a parent's console or allocate a new console, but it can call `AllocConsole` to get its own console window or `AttachConsole` to attach to the console of another process.. Then open the special file "CONIN$" to read from the console input buffer and "CONOUT$" to write to the console screen buffer.

Comment: @eryksun  Thank you.  That might be helpful.