# How to hide black cmd windows popping up when programs are executed

Tags: python, subprocess, exe, os.system

I made a python code which executes *polygon.exe* program like this:

```
    import os

    makecommand = "polygon -e 25 -l 25 pri 6 > hexagon.off"
    os.system(makecommand)
```

Then black cmd window pops up which implies that the *polygon.exe* program is working well.
Now, I want to hide the black cmd window that pops up when I run the python code.

I also tried using *subprocess* like this,

```
    import subprocess

    makecommand = "polygon -e 25 -l 25 pri 6 > hexagon.off"
    subprocess.run(makecommand)
```

but then the *polygon.exe* program was not executed and the wanted *hexagon.off* file was missing.

Is there any way to hide the black cmd window popping up in Python when programs are executed?
(For your information, *polygon.exe* program is a part of Antiprism project.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide console window in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689015/run-python-script-without-windows-console-appearing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294271/hiding-the-console-while-executing-a-script-on-windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47840633/hide-console-window-by-an-exe-file-executed-by-a-py-script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764631/how-to-hide-console-window-in-python

Answer (score 2):

if you want to hide the cmd when you execute the python file you just need to rename it to file.pyw